# How close to Neptune would I have to be to see it with the naked eye?

Tags: neptune

I am in space. What is the maximum distance that I could be from Neptune and see it with the naked eye. You can choose the optimal position. Also, assume that I have 20/20 vision.

Comment: What is the point of the question? Are to doing any calculation or is it a worldbuilding question?

Comment: Curiosity @NilayGhosh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately, Neptune is in an almost circular orbit that is almost in the same plane as that of the Earth. The [NASA planetary fact sheet](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/neptunefact.html) has Neptune at an apparent magnitude of 7.7 when it is $4.35\times 10^9$ km from Earth and the Sun, Earth and Neptune are in line.

If you were to move closer to Neptune along that line, it would grow brighter (but still appearing as a point source to the naked eye) as the inverse square of the distance to Neptune. Thus
$$7.7 - m = 5\log_{10}\left(\frac{4.35\times 10^9}{d}\right)\ ,$$
where $d$ is the distance you are looking for (in km) and $m$ is the apparent magnitude you think you can see with the naked eye - typically, $m=6$ for good vision in a dark sky.

This equation can be rearranged as
$$ d = 4.35\times 10^9\times 10^{(m-7.7)/5}\ {\rm km}. $$

e.g., for $m= 6$, $d = 1.99\times 10^9$ km.

Possibly you can do a bit better than $m=6$ out of the Earth's atmosphere. For $m=6.5$, $d = 2.50\times 10^9$ km.

Comment: That means Uranus comes close enough if it gets into proper alignment, so you might see Neptune from hovering above Uranus or a Uranian moon.